# Run built frontend (react) as a static file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux, ruby-on-rails-5

So I'm trying to run a React app as a static html file (it's index file) in a Rails app. This works in express/node and it's quite common in projects, but i can't find a solution for this in Rails. So the react app is already built and i'm trying to serve it as a static html from the /public folder. **EDIT** However i can't get it to run, it shows me that it's loaded, there's no error in the rails console or the browser console, however nothing gets shown on the screen.

routes.rb

```
get "react_app" => "projects#react_app"
```

projects_controller.rb

```
def react_app
  render :file => 'public/react_app/public/index.html'
end
```

i also have

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

I'm using Rails 5.2. I am not using yarn, i'm trying to run it via the plain assets pipeline.

Any ideas ? Or is there another better way to do it maybe ?

- This app needs to be all in one place, and unfortunately gems such as react-on-rails or react-rails are not an option, since they require too much strange customization and often crash due to Redux.

Comment: "Crash due to redux" doesn't make a lot of sense without context. What is/are the specific issue/issues? Is your controller hit? Is the file being served? Are JS files not being found? Please be explicit with the URL you're hitting and the exact nature of the problem(s).

Comment: those 2 gems do not offer good support for redux. once i install it within the app, the rails app stops seeing the App.js file or doesn't run it properly. That is why i'm looking into serving it as static

Comment: They work fine with Redux; react_on_rails *include* Redux, we had a massive project with react-rails with Redux that worked just fine. I'm not saying you *should* use either gem (we ended up dropping them for different reasons), I'm just saying redux + either works. You didn't answer any of my questions, so can't really help.

Comment: you didn't ask anything about my problem .... the question of the topic is how to run the react app as a static app. as for the react_on_rails comment ... did you integrate an already existing react app into it, or did you customize a react app within rails ? because that's a big difference

Comment: ah sorry i was confused by your sentence structure .. i edited the main question with what you've asked